# How much time will take for receiving 1 bag blood?

Tags: blood, blood-donation

I want an idea about time spent for taking 1 bag blood. I have a blood donor he will donate 1 bag blood. After taking his blood it will be transferred to a patient.

Would anyone provide an idea how much time this process may take to complete

Answer (score 2):

Normally whole blood is not used for transfusion purposes.  Instead it is separated into components which are then transfused after first being aggregated.  If someone needs a blood transfusion, then normally they are given packed red cells without platelets and without plasma.

The transfusion times are:

> The infusion rate for blood products depends on the clinical context, age and cardiac status of the patient. In stable, non-bleeding adult patients typical administrations details are:
>
> Red cells:                      1-3 hours
>
> Platelets:                       15-30 minutes
>
> Fresh frozen plasma:      30 minutes
>
> Cryoprecipitate:              30-60 minutes per standard adult dose

https://transfusion.com.au/transfusion_practice/administration